# Trying to pull fantasy football league data using PHP sample script from Yahoo

Tags: oauth, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-oauth

Just looking to pull league data from my league and import it into a local database. I feel like I am running in circles trying to troubleshoot this issue. I did register a new application in YDN. The link to the script I used is here:

https://developer.yahoo.com/fantasysports/guide/

and the error when running the script (using Ubuntu 16.04; permissions to the directory are 777):

```
Couldn't open /tmp/oauth_data_token_storage_dj0yJmk9V01CTGNUU1VtTXg1JmQ9WVdrOVNrTTBjbVJYTkRRbWNHbzlNQS0tJnM9Y29uc3VtZXJzZWNyZXQmeD0wOQ--.out, assuming we need to get a new request token.
Better try to get a new access token.
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 411, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```